# python request login to display my profile fails to bring my profile

Tags: python, python-requests

I was trying to read extract profile using Python `Request` libraries, it defaults back to login screen again as opposed to my profile screen. It is probably due to missing captcha. Any recommendation?

```
import sys
import requests


headers = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)",
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
}

loginInfo={
    'session-key' : 'username@gmail.com',
    'session-password' : 'password'
}

URL='https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit'
s=requests.session()
s.post(URL,data=loginInfo,headers=headers)

response=s.get('http://www.linkedin.com/nhome')

# print response.txt
```

Comment: Hm, not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but linked in has a REST API you'll want to use with requests: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api

Comment: Please follow @Joe's advice. LinkedIn is constantly updating their site to prevent webscraping. You will only be hurting future you by moving forward with webscraping.